# XML/HTML Read/Write

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I am developing a .Net application that involves reading data from XML and writing to HTML. The methods to do these tasks are all in the same class as the data they read/write are properties of objects of that class. The problem is that while they perform their function, they are rather long winded and complex. I would appreciate some ideas as to how I could neaten these methods up.

The class, data, and other functionality of this program ought to be irrelevant, but if requested, I'll give some more information. I just don't want this one post to get out of hand.

I'll show the methods in order of complexity according to CodeMaid/McCabe. First up is the HTML writing method at 11. This doesn't actually handle writing the HTML to a file, but returns a string with the HTML in it. About the first third of the method is "boilerplate" that does minimal work, mostly just writing HTML tags. The rest does more stuff, but I understand how someone who didn't write it could find it very confusing.

```
private String GetHtmlToWrite()
{
    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    using (HtmlTextWriter writer = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter))
    {
        writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Html);
        writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Head);
        writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Title);
        writer.Write(this.Title);
        writer.RenderEndTag();
        writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Href, ServerPath + ResetCssUrl);
        writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Type, "text/css");
        writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Rel, "stylesheet");
        writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Link);
        writer.RenderEndTag();
        writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Href, ServerPath + PdfCssUrl);
        writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Type, "text/css");
        writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Rel, "stylesheet");
        writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Link);
        writer.RenderEndTag();
        writer.RenderEndTag();
        writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Body);
        writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.H1);
        writer.Write(this.Title);
        writer.RenderEndTag();
        writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.H2);
        writer.Write("Standard Operating Procedure");
        writer.RenderEndTag();
        writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Table);
        writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Tr);

        int MetadataCount = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < this.Data.Count; i++)
        {
            if (this.Data[i].IsMetadata)
            {
                MetadataCount++;
            }
        }

        int numRows = (2 + MetadataCount) / 3;

        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
        {
            writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Class, "third-width");
            writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Td);
            writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Class, "inner");
            writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Table);
            for (int j = (i * numRows) - numRows; j < (i * numRows); j++)
            {
                if (j < MetadataCount)
                {
                    writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Tr);
                    writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Th);
                    writer.Write(this.Data[j].Title);
                    writer.RenderEndTag();
                    writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Td);
                    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.Data[j].Value))
                    {
                        writer.Write(this.Data[j].Value);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        writer.Write("NA");
                    }

                    writer.RenderEndTag();
                    writer.RenderEndTag();
                }
            }
            writer.RenderEndTag();
            writer.RenderEndTag();
        }
        writer.RenderEndTag();
        writer.RenderEndTag();

        for (int i = MetadataCount; i < this.Data.Count; i++)
        {
            if (this.Data[i].Value != null)
            {
                writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Div);
                writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.H3);
                writer.Write(this.Data[i].Title);
                writer.RenderEndTag();
                writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.P);
                string[] splitContent = Regex.Split(this.Data[i].Value, @"(?<=[<.+?>])");
                foreach (string line in splitContent)
                {
                    writer.Write(line);
                }
                writer.RenderEndTag();
                writer.RenderEndTag();
            }
        }
        writer.RenderEndTag();
        writer.RenderEndTag();
    }
    return stringWriter.ToString();
}
```

Up next we have the first of two XML read methods. This one loads a default data template file. Its complexity is 22.

```
private static List<StandardOperatingProcedureData> LoadDefaultStandardOperatingProcedureData()
{
    List<StandardOperatingProcedureData> data = new List<StandardOperatingProcedureData>();
    if (File.Exists(ServerPath + StandardOperatingProcedureDataConfigPath))
    {
        using (XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(ServerPath + StandardOperatingProcedureDataConfigPath))
        {
            string ID = null;
            string title = null;
            bool? isMetadata = null;
            bool? isRequired = null;
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.IsStartElement())
                {
                    switch (reader.Name)
                    {
                        case "ID":
                            if (reader.Read())
                            {
                                ID = reader.Value.Trim();
                            }
                            break;

                        case "Title":
                            if (reader.Read())
                            {
                                title = reader.Value.Trim();
                            }
                            break;

                        case "IsMetadata":
                            if (reader.Read())
                            {
                                switch (reader.Value.Trim().ToLower())
                                {
                                    case "false":
                                        isMetadata = false;
                                        break;

                                    case "true":
                                        isMetadata = true;
                                        break;

                                    default:
                                        throw new FileFormatException("Error: True/false incorrectly specified for field IsMetadata of data ID " + ID + ".");
                                }
                            }
                            break;

                        case "IsRequired":
                            if (reader.Read())
                            {
                                switch (reader.Value.Trim().ToLower())
                                {
                                    case "false":
                                        isRequired = false;
                                        break;

                                    case "true":
                                        isRequired = true;
                                        break;

                                    default:
                                        throw new FileFormatException("Error: True/false incorrectly specified for field IsRequired of data ID " + ID);
                                }
                            }
                            break;

                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
                if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ID) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(title) && isMetadata != null && isRequired != null)
                {
                    data.Add(new StandardOperatingProcedureData(ID, title, (bool)isMetadata, (bool)isRequired));
                    ID = null;
                    title = null;
                    isMetadata = null;
                    isRequired = null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("Error: SOPData configuration file 'config/sopdata.xml' not found.");
    }
    return data;
}
```

Finally, we have the second XML reader with a complexity of 28. It reads from a file that actually stores data for an object of the class. Ideally, I'll eventually replace this with SQL storage, but for now, XML will have to do.

```
public void LoadStandardOperatingProcedure(String xmlToLoadFileName)
{
    if (File.Exists(ServerPath + SopFolder + xmlToLoadFileName))
    {
        var data = new List<StandardOperatingProcedureData>();
        using (XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(ServerPath + SopFolder + xmlToLoadFileName))
        {
            string ID = null;
            string title = null;
            bool? isMetadata = null;
            bool? isRequired = null;
            string value = null;
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.IsStartElement())
                {
                    switch (reader.Name)
                    {
                        case "SOPTitle":
                            if (reader.Read())
                            {
                                this.Title = reader.Value.Trim();
                            }
                            break;

                        case "ID":
                            if (reader.Read())
                            {
                                ID = reader.Value.Trim();
                            }
                            break;

                        case "Title":
                            if (reader.Read())
                            {
                                title = reader.Value.Trim();
                            }
                            break;

                        case "IsMetadata":
                            if (reader.Read())
                            {
                                switch (reader.Value.Trim().ToLower())
                                {
                                    case "false":
                                        isMetadata = false;
                                        break;

                                    case "true":
                                        isMetadata = true;
                                        break;

                                    default:
                                        throw new FileFormatException("Error: True/false incorrectly specified for field IsMetadata of data ID " + ID + " in " + xmlToLoadFileName + ".");
                                }
                            }
                            break;

                        case "IsRequired":
                            if (reader.Read())
                            {
                                switch (reader.Value.Trim().ToLower())
                                {
                                    case "false":
                                        isRequired = false;
                                        break;

                                    case "true":
                                        isRequired = true;
                                        break;

                                    default:
                                        throw new FileFormatException("Error: True/false incorrectly specified for field IsRequired of data ID " + ID + " in " + xmlToLoadFileName + ".");
                                }
                            }
                            break;

                        case "Value":
                            if (reader.Read() && reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.CDATA)
                            {
                                value = reader.Value;
                            }
                            break;

                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
                if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ID) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(title) && isMetadata != null && isRequired != null && value != null)
                {
                    data.Add(new StandardOperatingProcedureData(ID, title, (bool)isMetadata, (bool)isRequired, value));
                    ID = null;
                    title = null;
                    isMetadata = null;
                    isRequired = null;
                    value = null;
                }
            }
        }
        this.Data = data;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("SOP file " + xmlToLoadFileName + " cannot be found.");
    }
}
```

It could be the case that the structure I am using for the XML files is needlessly long complex, so I am willing to discuss a restructuring/reformatting there. The default configuration file reads like this:

```xml
<SOPDataList>
  <SOPData>
    <ID>Department</ID>
    <Title>Department</Title>
    <IsMetadata>true</IsMetadata>
    <IsRequired>true</IsRequired>
  </SOPData>
  ...
</SOPDataList>
```

The actual data files read like this:

```xml
<StandardOperatingProcedure>
  <SOPTitle>Standard Operating Procedure</SOPTitle>
  <SOPDataList>
    <SOPData>
      <ID>Department</ID>
      <Title>Department</Title>
      <IsMetadata>True</IsMetadata>
      <IsRequired>True</IsRequired>
      <Value><![CDATA[Some Department]]></Value>
    </SOPData>
    ...
  </SOPDataList>
</StandardOperatingProcedure>
```

Comment: For reading the XML, I would suggest taking a look into [LINQ to XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb387098.aspx).

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what namespace does `HtmlWriter` belong to? I was looking for something like this a little while ago.

Comment: @RubberDuck you can view the documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmltextwriter(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @DanLyons Thanks, I'll look at that. However, my eventual goal is to use SQL for storing the data. XML is a temporary solution until the organization I am coding this for gets the infrastructure they need for SQL server.

Comment: Thanks @phantomjedi. I checked Web, but never looked at Web.UI. This looks handy.

Comment: @phantomjedi I wouldn't write off Linq-To-XML. With the write architecture, it shouldn't be hard to switch to Linq-To-SQL later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**private String GetHtmlToWrite()**

Because a `StringWriter` implements `IDisposable` it should be enclosed in a `using` statement too.

By extracting the writing of the default values of the `HtmlWriter` to a separate method the shown method will be reduced in size and will be more readable.

```
private void WriteDefaultValues(HtmlWriter writer)
{
    writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Title);
    writer.Write(this.Title);
    writer.RenderEndTag();
    writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Href, ServerPath + ResetCssUrl);
    writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Type, "text/css");
    writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Rel, "stylesheet");
    writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Link);
    writer.RenderEndTag();
    writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Href, ServerPath + PdfCssUrl);
    writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Type, "text/css");
    writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Rel, "stylesheet");
    writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Link);
    writer.RenderEndTag();
    writer.RenderEndTag();
    writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Body);
    writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.H1);
    writer.Write(this.Title);
    writer.RenderEndTag();
    writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.H2);
    writer.Write("Standard Operating Procedure");
    writer.RenderEndTag();
}
```

Extracting this

> ```
>     writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Table);
>     writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Tr);
>
>
>     int numRows = (2 + MetadataCount) / 3;
>
>     for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
>     {
>         writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Class, "third-width");
>         writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Td);
>         writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Class, "inner");
>         writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Table);
>         for (int j = (i * numRows) - numRows; j < (i * numRows); j++)
>         {
>             if (j < MetadataCount)
>             {
>                 writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Tr);
>                 writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Th);
>                 writer.Write(this.Data[j].Title);
>                 writer.RenderEndTag();
>                 writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Td);
>                 if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.Data[j].Value))
>                 {
>                     writer.Write(this.Data[j].Value);
>                 }
>                 else
>                 {
>                     writer.Write("NA");
>                 }
>
>                 writer.RenderEndTag();
>                 writer.RenderEndTag();
>             }
>         }
>         writer.RenderEndTag();
>         writer.RenderEndTag();
>     }
>     writer.RenderEndTag();
>     writer.RenderEndTag();
> ```

to a method `WriteMetaDataTable(HtmlWriter writer, int metadataCount)` will make again the code easier to read and maintain.

By using guard clauses you can reduce the vertical spacing which makes your code easier to read and to maintain.

A `if..else` like so

```
if (!condition)
{
    execute statement 1
}
else
{
    execute statement 2
}
```

is always easier to read if the `if` condition is a positiv one like so

```
if (condition)
{
    execute statement 2
}
else
{
    execute statement 1
}
```

Applying these points will lead to

```
private void WriteMetaDataTable(HtmlWriter writer, int metadataCount)
{

    writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Table);
    writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Tr);

    int numRows = (2 + metadataCount) / 3;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Class, "third-width");
        writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Td);
        writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Class, "inner");
        writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Table);

        for (int j = (i * numRows) - numRows; j < (i * numRows); j++)
        {
            if (j >= metadataCount) { continue; }

            writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Tr);
            writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Th);
            writer.Write(this.Data[j].Title);
            writer.RenderEndTag();
            writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Td);

            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.Data[j].Value))
            {
                writer.Write("NA");                
            }
            else
            {
                writer.Write(this.Data[j].Value);
            }

            writer.RenderEndTag();
            writer.RenderEndTag();

        }

        writer.RenderEndTag();
        writer.RenderEndTag();
    }
    writer.RenderEndTag();
    writer.RenderEndTag();

}
```

We can also simplify the counting of the metadata items

> ```
> int MetadataCount = 0;
>
> for (int i = 0; i < this.Data.Count; i++)
> {
>     if (this.Data[i].IsMetadata)
>     {
>         MetadataCount++;
>     }
> }
> ```

by using the extensionmethod `Count()` like so

```
int MetadataCount = this.Data.Count(x => x.IsMetaData)
```

this will let the `GetHtmlToWrite()` method look like this

```
private String GetHtmlToWrite()
{
    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    using (HtmlTextWriter writer = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter))
    {
        writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Html);
        writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Head);

        WriteDefaultValues(writer);

        int metadataCount = this.Data.Count(x => x.IsMetaData)

        WriteMetaDataTable(writer, metadataCount);

        for (int i = metadataCount; i < this.Data.Count; i++)
        {
            if (this.Data[i].Value == null) { continue; }

            writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Div);
            writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.H3);
            writer.Write(this.Data[i].Title);
            writer.RenderEndTag();
            writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.P);
            string[] splitContent = Regex.Split(this.Data[i].Value, @"(?<=[<.+?>])");
            foreach (string line in splitContent)
            {
                writer.Write(line);
            }
            writer.RenderEndTag();
            writer.RenderEndTag();

        }

        writer.RenderEndTag();
        writer.RenderEndTag();
    }
    return stringWriter.ToString();
}
```

I would also extract the remaining loops to a separate meaningful named method but will leave it to you.

Answer (score 4):

I would start by simplifying the *ugly* `switch/case` like this:

```
private static List<StandardOperatingProcedureData> LoadDefaultStandardOperatingProcedureData()
{
    // I suggest to throw an exeption right away if something's wrong
    // and not in the else block later. This way you have fewer nested blocks.
    if (!File.Exists(ServerPath + StandardOperatingProcedureDataConfigPath))
    {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("Error: SOPData configuration file 'config/sopdata.xml' not found.");
    }

    using (XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(ServerPath + StandardOperatingProcedureDataConfigPath))
    {
        string ID = null;
        string title = null;

        // This variables don't have to be nullable because if the value isn't true or false you throw an exception anyway.
        bool isMetadata;
        bool isRequired;
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.IsStartElement())
            {
                switch (reader.Name)
                {
                case "ID": 
                    reader.IfRead(r => ID = r.Value.Trim());
                    break;

                case "Title":
                    reader.IfRead(r => title = r.Value.Trim());
                    break;

                case "IsMetadata":
                    reader.IfRead(r =>
                    {
                        if (!bool.TryParse(r.Value.Trim(), out isMetadata))
                        {
                            throw new FileFormatException("Error: True/false incorrectly specified for field IsMetadata of data ID " + ID + ".");
                        }
                    });                           
                    break;

                case "IsRequired":
                    reader.IfRead(r =>
                    {
                        if (!bool.TryParse(r.Value.Trim(), out isRequired))
                        {
                            throw new FileFormatException("Error: True/false incorrectly specified for field IsMetadata of data ID " + ID + ".");
                        }
                    });
                    break;
                }
            }

            // I would create the list where necessary and not at the top above all other code and use it later.
            List<StandardOperatingProcedureData> data = new List<StandardOperatingProcedureData>();

            // Not necessary to check isMetadata and isRequired because if the value is invalid you throw an exception
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ID) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(title))
            {
                data.Add(new StandardOperatingProcedureData(ID, title, isMetadata, isRequired));
                // You don't have to reset the values before leaving the method. They go out of scope and vanish anyway.
            }
        }
    }
    return data;
}
```

I like extensions that remove *logic* from code if this logic repeats often so I'd created an extension for it:

```
static class XmlTextReaderExtensions
{
    public static void IfRead(this XmlTextReader reader, Action<XmlTextReader> action)
    {
        if (reader.Read()) action(reader);
    }
}
```

---

You could also simplify the `while` and `using` blocks by moving the *logic* to somewhere else. I used an anonymous function for it:

```
private static List<StandardOperatingProcedureData> LoadDefaultStandardOperatingProcedureData()
{
    if (!File.Exists(ServerPath + StandardOperatingProcedureDataConfigPath))
    {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("Error: SOPData configuration file 'config/sopdata.xml' not found.");
    }

    string ID = null;
    string title = null;

    // This variables don't have to be nullable because if the value isn't true or false you throw an exception anyway.
    bool isMetadata;
    bool isRequired;

    var readProperties = new Action<XmlTextReader>(reader =>
    {
        if (!reader.IsStartElement())
        {
            return;
        }
        switch (reader.Name)
        {
        case "ID":
            reader.IfRead(r => ID = r.Value.Trim());
            break;

        case "Title":
            reader.IfRead(r => title = r.Value.Trim());
            break;

        case "IsMetadata":
            reader.IfRead(r =>
            {
                if (!bool.TryParse(r.Value.Trim(), out isMetadata))
                {
                    throw new FileFormatException(
                        "Error: True/false incorrectly specified for field IsMetadata of data ID " + ID +
                        ".");
                }
            });
            break;

        case "IsRequired":
            reader.IfRead(r =>
            {
                if (!bool.TryParse(r.Value.Trim(), out isRequired))
                {
                    throw new FileFormatException(
                        "Error: True/false incorrectly specified for field IsMetadata of data ID " + ID +
                        ".");
                }
            });
            break;
        }
    });

    using (XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(ServerPath + StandardOperatingProcedureDataConfigPath))
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            readProperties(reader);
        }
    }

    List<StandardOperatingProcedureData> data = new List<StandardOperatingProcedureData>();
    // Not necessary to check isMetadata and isRequired because if the value is invalid you throw an exception
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ID) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(title))
    {
        data.Add(new StandardOperatingProcedureData(ID, title, isMetadata, isRequired));
        // You don't have to reset the values before leaving the method. They go out of scope and vanish anyway.
    }

    return data;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Any suggestions as to the HTML write method?

Comment: I know but still thinking ;-)